# Re-rendering page after new user Input

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rendering

To preface this question, I am fairly junior with my react experience. I am currently trying to build a "to-do" list, that has multiple inputs within creating the "todo". So a user will input their todo item, their description of their item, its urgency, and date. I am using hooks to save each input to state and my thought process is to then push each value to an array. I would then pass that array down as a prop, to my todo list component and then map through each array. My problem is, when I try to add a new input, the component I am calling isn't updating and still shows the one and only item I have put in. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Also, if anyone has any thoughts on clearing the input fields after hitting submit, that would be great and thank you!

**Home**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Todo from '../TodoList/Todo';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';

const Home = () => {
    const [dateValue, onChangeDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [urgency, setUrgency] = useState('');
    const [showList, setShowList] = useState(false);
    const [todoArray, setTodoArray] = useState([]);
    const [descriptionArray, setDescriptionArray] = useState([]);
    const [urgencyArray, setUrgencyArray] = useState([]);

    const todoOnChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setTodo(event.target.value);
    };
    const descriptionOnChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setDescription(event.target.value);
    };
    const urgencyOnChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setUrgency(event.target.value);
    };

    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setShowList(true);
        todoArray.push(todo);
        descriptionArray.push(description);
        urgencyArray.push(urgency);
        componentDidMount()
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <header> Task Buddy </header>
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        {' '}
                        To-Do:
                        <input type='text' name='task' onChange={todoOnChangeHandler} />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        {' '}
                        Description:{' '}
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='description'
                            onChange={descriptionOnChangeHandler}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label onChange={urgencyOnChangeHandler}>
                        Urgency:
                        <select>
                            <option> High </option>
                            <option> Medium</option>
                            <option> Low</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Date: <Calendar onChange={onChangeDate} value={dateValue} />
                    </label>
                    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
                </form>
                {showList && (
                    <div>
                        <Todo
                            todoArray={todoArray}
                            descriptionArray={descriptionArray}
                            urgencyArray={urgencyArray}
                        />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

**todo**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Todo.css';

const Todo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='listContainer'>
            {props.todoArray.map((x, index) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {' '}
                        {x} + {index}{' '}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            {props.descriptionArray.map((y, index) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {' '}
                        {y} + {index}{' '}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Todo;
```

Comment: React components update when state or props is updated. For react to be notified about a state update you need to set state in the appropriate manner. For example: Where you are using `todoArray.push(todo);` you should instead be using something similar to `setTodoArray([...todoArray, todo])`. You need to create a new array when updating the state as React uses reference comparisons for non-primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change todoArray.push(todo) for setTodoArray([...todoArray, todo]) in the onSubmit function. And the same for descriptionArray and urgencyArray.